# factory for product templates

Tags: c++, templates, factory-pattern

I'm writing my own implementation of hash_table (just for fun). I would like to implement a series of hashing routines and give the user a chance to pick one with an ID. For that I would like to use a factory which would produce appropriate hasher. The hashers are class templates. Is it possible to write a factory for product templates without using anything like typelists to specify every possible type provided ? I'm most concerned about product registration.

More general. My products are:

```
template <typename X>
class i_prod
{
};

template <typename X>
class c_prod_a : public i_prod {

};

template <typename X>
class c_prod_b : public i_prod {

};
```

The factory is also a class template. But how to sort out the registration process ?

Comment: You're using some really weird jargon there, for example "class templates" (which normally refer to the declaration of template classes, not instances) and "product templates" (I have no idea what this is).  Also, you haven't said anything about how product templates fit into this story.

Comment: Unless you want to switch the hashing function *at runtime*, a factory is not the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use a traits `class` `template` with the id as the `template` argument.  To register an id, you specialize the traits class, which can be done distributively.  You can use `enum` or an integral type for the id, but that makes collisions hard to avoid.

Instead you can use tag `struct`s that just act as identifiers, like iterator tags.

This can all be resolved at compile tine.

Comment: I never used those. Just read an article about them and it seems very interesting and it would eliminate a need for a factory in my code. I'll think about that. Thanks